# Interpreting admission requirements

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I am reading through the application requirements for [this programme](https://www.tudelft.nl/en/education/admission-and-application/msc-international/1-admission-requirements/#c41663). However, as far as I see it, there are some ambiguities

> **Motivation**
>
> A clear and relevant essay in English (1,000 – 1,500 words)

I contacted an experienced prof. working for admissions committees and she emphasized that a letter of motivation should not exceed 1.5 pages. Also, words "clear and relevant" makes me feel that 5 page "sheet of text" is way too much. On the other hand, there is "essay" in the quote above, which maybe makes the word count relevant. I currently have a concentrated letter of motivation with about 350 words in it (1 page) that includes all the points that must be covered.

In my opinion, 1000 - 1500 words feel bloated. I am interpreting the numbers given as the maximum top boundaries for the essay / letter. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I usually think that there are 750 words on a page with narrow margins and a small font. 350 words is way too short as 1 paragraph abstracts are often 250 words.

Comment: This looks entirely unambiguous to me. They ask for a clear and relevant essay containing 1000-1500 words. So give them a clear and relevant essay containing 1000-1500 words.

Comment: The essay prompt you cite includes 5 points. Why don't you edit your question to include them? Also, if I had to write your essay, I would subtract off the summary word count and then divide the word count by the remaining number of prompts.

Answer (score 9):

By giving you a word range (1000-1500 words) they are telling you how much detail they want the letter to go into. Your 350 word letter is likely too superficial.

Give them what they are asking for. "Does not follow instructions" is generally not a good look.